# React Native Android app release build (using Hermes) is only slow when downloaded through the Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-hermes

We have a React Native Android app with Hermes enabled. We are seeing a huge performance issue with our app when it is downloaded through the Play Store (7s+ boot time). The same build runs very fast when installed directly in APK format (<2s boot time).

Has anyone experienced this before? What are some factors that causes this discrepancy between the Play Store installation vs direct APK installation of the same build.

Additional info

- react-native: 0.63.4
- enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture=true
- enableProguardInReleaseBuilds=false

Comment: Use aab, turn on ram bundle, turn on inline requires, clean the build before deployment.

Comment: Did you end up finding out what this was?  We are having the same issue after upgrading to 0.71 with hermes